# 'Error: Plugin name should be specified' @svgr/webpack svgoConfig

Tags: reactjs, svg, webpack

I have `@svgr/webpack@6.0.0` installed and webpack config as below

```
use: [
    {
        loader: '@svgr/webpack',
        options: {
            svgoConfig: {
                plugins: [
                    {
                        removeViewBox: false,
                    },
                ],
            },
        },
    },
],
```

But I am getting an error as below:

```
Error: Plugin name should be specified
```

Comment: Not an answer but same issue for me in Gatsby using `gatsby-plugin-svgr` and `@svgr/webpack`

Comment: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@svgr/webpack/dist/index.js):
Error: Plugin name should be specified
    at resolvePluginConfig (L:\my-project\node_modules\svgo\lib\svgo\config.js:113:13)

Comment: I think your syntax is out of date. Each plugin object now requires a "name" property/value according to the latest svgo documentation.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The latest SVGO documentation suggests that you need to assign each plugin object a name. Your configuration is out of date so it's most likely a version/update issue. Try changing the options object in your config to:

```
svgoConfig: {
  plugins: [
    {
      name: 'preset-default',
      params: {
        overrides: {
          // disable plugins
          removeViewBox: false,
        },
      },
    },
  ],
},
```

The `preset-default` plugin allows you to customise the defaults and allows you to disable plugins that are enabled by default.